# Get Chromecast to run in a secure context when connected to local dev server

Tags: javascript, security, google-cast, drm

I have adopted a codebase for a Chromecast app for one of our major clients. This has been handed over to me because the original developer has recently left our company. Upon trying to do a handover, however, we were surprised to find that the Chromecast client (which is a simple JavaScript SPA) does not run when hosted by my machine! The content requires use of the `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` API for DRM-protected video, which is not available on my host, but is available on my ex-colleague's.

After much investigation, the root cause seems to the fact that the Chromecast does not deem my dev server's host (something like `http://10.1.2.75:4301`) a "secure context" - the `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` API is only available in such secure contexts. However, the old developer of this project has been connecting the Chromecast to *their* local dev server (something like `http://10.1.2.89:4301`) just fine for more than 2 years, he was completely surprised to find that it didn't work for anybody else. We ran numerous tests for different configurations, tried casting from different sources, connecting to different people's machines, etc. but whenever we inspected `window.isSecureContext` on his host it would return `true` - and on mine it would return `false`.

From my understanding, there should basically be no scenario where `isSecureContext` should be true on any kind of `http` connection, and yet this was very much the case on my ex-colleague's machine - and had been for a long period of time. If this hadn't been the case and this were a new project I was starting I would immediately say "we're going to need to develop this on some sort of HTTPS connection", and yet the evidence I have disproves this.

How can I get the Chromecast to trust my browser enough to expose this `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` API - it should be all I need to get this project working without some kind of local tunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (which is what I'm having to do at the moment, and it is causing all sorts of issues). In Chrome you can explicitly instruct a website to trust insecure content - is there a way that I can do this on the Chromecast device? Is there a way I can get it to trust a self-signed certificate or something?

Lastly, I can't realistically do much stuff at a network level like set up a private CA and provision certs to dev machines, etc, as we are a pretty small company with little-to-no in-house architecture (so that we needn't maintain anything). I also don't like the idea of telling future devs on this project that the way of running this project is "long list of shenanigans that only I understand".

Any help or advice on this would be much appreciated!

**Update**: I accidentally left my Chromecast pointing directly to my local dev server and managed to recreate the working scenario, which I took a screenshot of. I assume this won't last very long, so here's exactly what I'm talking about. This is possible:

[image: A picture of the dev tools console showing that location.href is http://10.1.2.75:4301 and isSecureContext is true]

Comment: Have you tried running things on https instead, with a letsencrypt certificate? Because whatever setup your ex-colleague had bears zero relevance to how things _should_ work, and you should probably try https anyway, not assume that won't work just because their computer was set up in some crazy way.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. But I'm not sure of a reasonable way to achieve HTTPS. LetsEncrypt will only issue me a cert for a domain I can prove I own, which means I'd just be back to running some kind of local tunnel so that domain points to my development machine. I am currently using ngrok for exactly this reason. In my experience most dev work is not done over HTTPS as it is easier and there is little to protect - you are just connecting to your own machine over LAN. 

My colleague has no "setup" as far as he is aware!

Comment: not really? you can self-sign certificates. https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/